# PHP file to return content of XML File

Tags: php, xml, file, server

I am facing a problem in reading content of XML File that is hosted on my server via PHP.
In my hosting directory i have 1 PHP file & other 3 are XML files.
XML files are already filled. They have text data. All  I need is that if I pass Value1 to my php file, it should read File1.xml & return its content as it is. If I pass Value2 to my php file, it should read File2.xml & return its content as it is. I tried to search here on Stackoverflow but didn't find anything related to this specific problem.

Comment: not funny how all answers suggest to implement a script where everyone can read any file on your system. nice.

Comment: @ins0 Not all the files but only XMLs from 1 given location.

Comment: wrong please lookup ``nullbytes``

Comment: @ins0 It was fixed in 5.3: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `file_get_contents` or `cURL` for getting a content and then: `SimpleXML` for parsing XML.

```
$file = $_GET['xml_file'];
$xml = file_get_contents($file.'.xml');

$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $simpleXml->__toString();
```

Then usage will be something like: `my.php?xml_file=file1`

Answer (score 1):

[See `file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents($_POST["value"]);
?>
```

Comment: best and most ez answer

Answer (score 0):

These should fit your requirement.

```
$xml = file_get_contents( $_POST['value'] );
$xml = trim( $xml );
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $xml;
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to treat the file as XML, actually. But you should match it against a whitelist in you script, so people can not request any file on your server. With the content type header you can inform the browser that you're sending an XML file.

```
$files = [
  'file1' => 'File1.xml',
  'file2' => 'File2.xml',
  'file3' => 'File3.xml'
];

if (isset($_GET['file']) && isset($files[$_GET['file']])) {
  header('Content-Type: text/xml');
  readfile($files[$_GET['file']]);
} else {
  echo 'Invalid file parameter.';
}
```